# camera2 continuous image streaming

Tags: android, android-asynctask, streaming, android-camera2

currently trying to create the front-end for my Convolutional neural network image classifier.
what i'm trying to build is an app which sends a continuous stream of images to my server for classification, the total stream classification will be averaged and viewed for the user. 
the reason i want this specific trait is because classifying many images of the same 3D object could improve accuracy.

building the app on camera2 demo from github, i wasn't able to google a solution.

i have tried creating a Asynctask which will rerun the `takePhoto()` method at `onPostExecute` but canceling the task is close to impossible, without talking about rerunning the task which doesnt allow me to cancel because i'm not saving the task as a variable.

also, each time i take a picture the device stutters a bit, is this unavoidable using camera2?

i have thought about moving to the older camera api, camera2 is a complete pain in the `a**`.

any new idea would be lovely at this point.
would apreciate if anyone who was able to stream images easily using camera2 or the older ap  could post an example or help me with the issue.

this is my asynctask if this actualy could work and im just doing it wrong:

```
public class AsyncTakePicture extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private boolean running = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        running = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        while (running) {
            takePicture();
            try {
                // no need for alot of images, so one image per 2 seconds is good
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                running = false;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if (running){
            myAsyncTask.execute();
        } else {
            Log.i("AsyncTask:"," done");
        }
    }
}
```

the idea is that once the task is called, it will rerun and take more photos until cancelled. Async is called because i don't want the UI to lag. thing is, to repeat the task i cannot initiate it as a variable, and if i cannot initiate then i cannot use `cancel(boolean)`.